# What's the point of the winstring.h header?

Tags: c, api, winapi, crt

A header file was added to the Windows API in Windows 8 which appears to be filled with pretty basic string functions that are all already available in the C runtime. There doesn't appear to be any reason why these functions would be added to the Windows API.

I only found out about them because they're used in explorer.exe

Why use these functions instead of the classic cstring ones?

Comment: It is a WinRT-specific header, available to create and manipulate [HSTRING strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrt/hstring).  Something you'd do when you create an app to publish in the store and write your code in C or create your own language projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [winstring.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winstring/) header provides string handling functions for [`HSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrt/hstring) values, a string type introduced with the Windows Runtime. It is the successor to the [`BSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr) type used in COM.

Either one is distinctly different from a C-style string in that they explicitly store the length. A corollary of this is that either one can contain embedded NUL characters, making it impossible to reliably get the string length by calling [`wcslen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strlen-wcslen-mbslen-mbslen-l-mbstrlen-mbstrlen-l) on them, for example.

In addition, neither `HSTRING` nor `BSTR` have a dependency on any given language runtime (such as the CRT). Use of either type will thus not interfere with the language runtime used by clients. Obviously, this necessitates providing string handling functions outside a language runtime, hence we have *winstring.h* (and *oleauto.h*).

Comment: I wouldn't call HSTRING "the successor of BSTR". BSTR is a COM Automation (which is sort of an addon to COM) type initially created for Visual Basic and subsequently used for scripting languages (VBScript, JScript, etc.). It's often used, but it's not mandatory for working with strings in COM.

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm not aware of a string type other than `BSTR` in COM that can be marshaled. As such, `HSTRING` isn't just the successor to `BSTR` in spirit. I'm also pretty sure that `HSTRING` is an ABI-compatible extension to `BSTR` (though finding documentation on the internals is near impossible; even the *hstring.h* header file has `HSTRING_HEADER` declared as ultimately a bunch of bytes).

Comment: PWSTR, etc. can be marshaled. Any type in COM can be marshaled if you have the proper proxy/stub. When oleaut(32) was created, it was called the "universal marshaler" back then because as long as you stick to COM automation types (VARIANT and friends, including BSTR), you didn't need a proxy/stub since this was created automatically and dynamically by it from a type library. That's why many developers used BSTR, because the marshaler is already built-in and well-known by the system and you don't need an extra proxy/stub dll

Comment: @SimonMourier You cannot marshal a `PWSTR`. For one, you cannot know its length with certainty. And even if you did, there's literally no way for you to know which allocator was used to allocate the memory referenced. `BSTR` solves both of these issues. `BSTR` having its origins in OLE automation does not invalidate the fact that it **is** the de-facto string type for COM. Now, if you wouldn't call `HSTRING` a successor of `BSTR`, what would you call it instead? And why?

Comment: Most of Windows APIs use marshaled zero-terminated PWSTR when they don't need to be used by scripting languages. For example this function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitem-getdisplayname works cross-thread and cross-process because it's declared with proper marshaling attributes (in shobjidl_core.idl) and there's a proxy for it. HSTRING has nothing to do with BSTR (it's not stored like a BSTR in memory), it's just another type of string, invented for the Windows Runtime.

Comment: @SimonMourier *"HSTRING has nothing to do with BSTR (it's not stored like a BSTR in memory)"* - You seem pretty confident here. I doubt you are correct, though (as I noted earlier). Opinions aside, is there anything you would suggest to substantially improve this proposed answer?

Comment: Look in a debugger at an HSTRING memory and you'll see it has nothing to do. I don't say your answer is bad, if it was me, I wouldn't say that HSTRING is not a successor to BSTR :-)